# What is the best way to position child elements within a parent div?

Tags: css

Check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r49nvfvv/). I want to position the blue and black div exactly at the right and bottom of the red div respectively. I want the right vertex of the blue div to align with the right vertex of the red one and the bottom vertex of the black div to align with the bottom vertex of the red one. What is the best way to do that?
Thank You in advance.

The HTML

```
<div id="diamond">
<div id="diamond_right"></div>
<div id="diamond_bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
#diamond {
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 300px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: red;
position: relative;
top: -300px;
z-index:0;
}

#diamond:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -300px;
top: 300px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 300px solid transparent;
border-top-color: red;
}

#diamond_right {

width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: blue;
position: relative;
top: -50px;
z-index:1;
}

#diamond_right:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
top: 50px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top-color: blue;
}

#diamond_bottom {

width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: black;
position: relative;
top: -50px;
z-index:2;

}

#diamond_bottom:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
top: 50px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier to do this with a single normal div and a couple of pseudo elements using standard techniques and then rotate the whole lot together.

```css
#diamond {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  margin: 75px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
#diamond::before,
#diamond::after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
#diamond::before {
  background: blue;
  right: 0;
}
#diamond::after {
  background: black;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="diamond"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with the blue one in your fiddle and it aligned with the right vertex, if you plug this in is this what you were looking to achieve?

```
#diamond_right {

width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: blue;
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
right: -300px;
z-index:1;
}

#diamond_right:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: -50px;
top: 50px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border: 50px solid transparent;
border-top-color: blue;
}
```